# OCaml modules and signatures

Tags: module, ocaml, signature

In my exercise I have to write OCaml module given its signiture:

```
module type Range
 = sig
   type t
   val range : int * int -> t
   (*val list_of_range : t -> int list*)
 end
```

The module I have so far:

```
module Range = 
  struct
  type t = int
  let range (n,m) = 
    if m > n then () else (n,m)
  end
```

The task for range (n,m) is to take 2 integers and if n <= m then give out a tuple (n,m). Otherwise (). If I try to run this code, I get error **The expression has 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type unit**. Can anyone help me to move forward with this?

PS. It's my first day with OCaml.

PPS. I have commented out the **list of range..** part because this is the second part of the exercise and wouldn't work anyway if the first part isn't working.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code and results seem promising.

```
module type Range
 = sig
   type t
   val range : int * int -> t
   val list_of_range : t -> int list
 end

module Range = 
  struct
  type t = int

  let range (m,n) = 
    if m > n then (0,0) else (m,n)      

  let rec list_of_range (m,n) = 
    let t = range(m,n) in 
    let x = fst(t) in let y = snd(t) in
    if x = 0 && y = 0 then [0] else x :: list_of_range(x+1,y)
  end
```

The code above gives me almost perfect expected result. If I give input (1,5), the result is [1;2;3;4;5;0]. The problem is the **0** as the last element in the list. Why is is there? Where does it come from?

Comment: this is because your recursive function terminates necessarily with a invalid range,  yielding (0,0) and then [0]. this [0] is merged with all the other "valid" values.

Comment: if (0,0) only occurs in case of invalid range, then just change [0] to []. or you have to find another way to discriminate the invalid range from valid range ; using a specific type.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue comes from your function range, it cannot return a unit type (i.e. () ) and a tuple. In addition, it violates the signature, where you define range as a function that returns an int.

Comment: Thank you, understood the first part. I replaced **()** with **(n, m)**.
But now I have a new question, you mention that it violates the the signature. The function _range_ needs to give out range so the function _list_of_range_ can give integers from n to m as a list. What should range output  be in that case?

Comment: I would propose that range output a list : either an empty list when m>n else [n;m]. And then list_of_range takes a range as input and either returns an empty list, or the list of ints.